# Is AWS DynamoDB fit for data collecting and analysis app?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I'm building a simple let's say survey app. I have the following requirements:

```
User: 
- name 
- surname 
- age

Question: 
- question (text) 
- type 
- author

Answer: 
- value 
- date
```

I want users to give questions to answers and I want to be able to query the following:

- Get user's questions and answers
- Get question and its answers
- Get user's questions and answers by (or where) type
- Get answers to questions by value (or where value)
- Count answers to a question
- Get answers to a question by user age
- Get answers to questions over time (by user or general)

So far I came up with the following solution:

[image]

So here the Partition Key is the ID and the Sort Key is type

So the first problem is the first requirement:

- Get user's questions and answers

Shall I add another type which would be `user` ?

Now how to:

- get a question and its answers ?

I can query `id = 1 and type starts with question` but then I can get a lot of unnecessary `user` records.

Now the next one:

- get user's answers to questions of specific type (type as question attribute)
- How to count same answers to a question?

I'm new to DynamoDB so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would add an id (uuid generated from code) for each table.

> Get user's questions and answers

Set userId as field in both Question and Answer, then set an index on that. This will allow you (with 2 separate queries) to get all questions and answer of a particular user.

> get a question and its answers ?

Answer will have as field questionId and same index principle applies

> get user's answers to questions of specific type (type as question attribute)

You can add a field to Answer, which is questionType and filter on that. Remember that NoSQL schema focuses on the queries you need, not for a perfect normalised schema.

> How to count same answers to a question?

I am guessing you meant how many answers does a question have. Well if you know the questionId, just follow "get a question and its answers ?" and execute a `.withSelect(Select.COUNT)` on the query

**EDIT**

```
User: 
- userId (hash key)
- name 
- surname 
- age

Question: 
- questionId (hash key)
- question (text) 
- type 
- author
- askedByUserId (index - hash key)

Answer: 
- answerId (hash key)
- value 
- date 
- answeredByUserId (index - hash key)
- questionId (index - hash key)
```

So everything depends on how you query data (and of course you may end up switching to SQL even, noSQL not an 1:1 replacement). Referring just by id is not wrong, I would prefer to have immutable questions and answers instead of editing a question every time it receives an answer. So take into consideration that you can't use joins and always prefer immutable data (add a new value instead of editing).

**EDIT 2**

In order to get all questions and answers from a User, create and manage this table:

```
UserItems:
- userId (hash key)
- question (full json of a question, optional)
- answer (full json of a answer, optional)
```

So every time you create a new question for example, add it to both Question and UserItems. Do a simple query based on hash key and you will get all questions and answers, with full data. Again, this is based on your querying needs.

Comment: Hmm... so isn't it that putting "relations" to other records in a record, like userId in both Question and Answer make the database model "relational" which should be avoided in NoSQL models? I've watched 2 AWS videos about DynamoDB so far and haven't seen this solution yet. I could add questionId, answerId, userId all over to other records and to me it seems like a relational model. Maybe you could visualise your answer with the table? I might be missing the point

Comment: Can you also explain how would you query for example all the questions and answers of a particular user? Can you do it in one query without doing roundtrips to the server? The example query would be great if you could write one.

Comment: Personally, I would do 2 queries, on the index askedByUserId from Question and on the index answeredByUserId from Answer. They are different entities so it's not wrong. Is there a way to do just with 1 query? Possible, but it needs a schema change and I feel comfortable with mine. If response time is your concern, do both calls async. I will add and edit on the answer on how to do both with one query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, I answered the question myself. Would be good to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it took me a few good hours to figure out the answer.

Let's start with the entities and their relationships, here is the diagram:

[image]

Where:

- USR - User
- ANS - Answer
- QUE - Question

As it can be seen above, I don't have any many-to-many relationships so the only pattern I will be using for retrieving the data is the Primary Key (Partition Key + Selection Key) pattern.

If I had many-to-many relationship in the model, apart from PK+SK I would also use GSI (Global Secondary Index)
GSI can also be used to create a different view, for example by swapping places of PK with SK.

Now the DB access patterns:

[image]

The above unfortunately doesn't cover all the access patterns, a few more I can think of are:

- Query answers by user age
- Query answers to a question and calculate percentage of answers by type (should this be calculated outside of the DynamoDB?)

And now the DB Table design:

[image]

So based on the access patterns in the Access Patterns table with this design I can query:

1. All the answers of a user to a question

   - **SELECT PK=USR_1 WHERE SK begins_with(AR_QUE_2)**
2. All the answers to all the question by a user

   - **SELECT PK=USR_1 WHERE SK begins_with(AR_QUE)** - in this case I would have to include question metadata (question itself as text) in the attributes of the AR_QUE_X_ANS_Y so that I don't have to query the table multiple times to get all the questions metadata.
3. All the answers to a question

   - **Select PK=QUE_2**

I'd really love to hear someone's opinion on this one.
I also appreciate that in some cases I would have to denormalise data and insert metadata information in Attributes.

**I am still very curious how I could calculate number of answers by type to a question and calculate for example a percentage of answers of different type.**